# Objective C - Method Definition not in @implementation context

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, objective-c-runtime

My Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

-(NSString *) Fibonacci:(int) number{
//Fibonacci Calculations
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Fibonacci Output: %@", Fibonacci(5));
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

I am very new to Objective-C world and hence am not able to get the above working.
Facing the following errors:

**Error(s):
source_file.m:5:1: error: method definition not in @implementation context
 -(NSString *) lastdigitsFibonacci:(int) number{
 ^
source_file.m:6: confused by earlier errors, bailing out**

Any help on the above would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Who-So-Ever-Downvoted-The-Question: Care explaining what made you do so?

Comment: `Fibonacci(5)` seems to be like a function. `-(NSString *) Fibonacci:(int) number` seems to be like a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Larme said, **Fibonacci(5) seems to be like a function. -(NSString *) Fibonacci:(int) number seems to be like a method.**

So to call `Fibonacci(5)`, you should rewrite `-(NSString *) Fibonacci:(int) number` as a func.

```
NSString* Fibonacci(int number) {

  int t1 = 0;
  int t2 = number > 1 ? 1 : 0;
  int tmp;

  for (int i = 3; i <= number; i++) {
    tmp = t2;
    t2 += t1;
    t1 = tmp;
  }

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", t2];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSLog(@"%@", Fibonacci(999));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot  for the answer. :)

Comment: & @Sangram S.

can you please help me out printing the output for n=999 in fibonacci series.

**NSUInteger t1=0, t2=1,i=0,nextTerm;
    //NSLog(@"%i", number);
    for (i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
    {
        //NSLog(@"%i", t1);
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = nextTerm;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"----> %lu",t1);**

Comment: @genius_monkey Updated my answer. Good luck guy ;)

Comment: Don’t call UI applicationmain()

Comment: @bbum Thanks Sir !

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString*  Fibonacci(int number) ;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Fibonacci Output: %@", Fibonacci(5));

    }
    return 0;
}

NSString*  Fibonacci(int number)
{
    //Fibonacci Calculations and return
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for Pointing Out the Difference. Appreciate it :)